# Inserindo registros no banco de dados a partir de um arquivo

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando inserir registros no meu banco de dados, especificamente no model `Participante` a partir de um arquivo `.csv`, cujo formato é id, nome, cpf e email.

Até agora o que eu tenho no meu `views.py` é:

```
def presenca(request):

        form = UploadArquivo()
        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formulario = UploadArquivo(request.POST, request.FILES)
            #data_evento = '-'.join(formulario.data['data'].split('/')[::-1])

            if formulario.is_valid():
                formulario.save(commit=False)
                formulario.save()

                arquivo = str(request.FILES.getlist('upload_csv')[0])           # pega o nome do arquivo
                                
            f = open('csv/' + arquivo.replace(' ', '_'), 'r')
                                
            for line in f:
                line = line.split(',')                          # separado por vírgula

                participante = Participante.objects.filter(cpf=line[2])  # pega o CPF da planilha
                                                
                if participante:        # se o cpf está preenchido
                    verifica = Participante.objects.filter(cpf=participante)   # verifica se o cpf da planilha coincide com algum do banco
                                                    
                    if not verifica:        # se nao coincide
                        cadastra = Participante.objects.create(participante__nome=line[0], participante__cpf=line[1], participante__email=line[2])
                        presenca = Participante(cadastra).save()        # salva os dados do participante no model Participante
                                                        
            f.close()

            return render(request, 'base.html', locals())
```

Mas não está salvando no banco.
Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, eu agradeceria demais. Grata desde já pela atenção!!

Comment: Como está o model? Mais precisamente `Participante`.

Comment: ```class Participante(models.Model):
          nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
          cpf = models.CharField(max_length=13)
          email = models.EmailField()
          dt_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

atualizada a resposta:
Urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import  CarregarView #, carrega ,
urlpatterns = [
   # path('carregar1/', carrega),
    path('carregar2/', CarregarView.as_view())
```

]

Forms:

```
from django import forms


class ContatoForm(forms.Form):
    objeto1 = forms.CharField(required=True)
    objeto2 = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

Model:

```
from django.db import models


class ExemploModel(models.Model):
    objeto1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objeto2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ExemploModel
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import ContatoForm

#função
# def carrega(request): #Ao acessar a pagina carregara o arquivo e salvara no banco
#     #csv
#     for i in range(1,19):
#         carregar = ExemploModel(objeto1=f"informacao{i}", objeto2=f'dados2 {i}')
#         carregar.save()
#     return render(request, "carregar.html")



#class
class CarregarView(View):

    def get(self, request): # na requisição get, quando acessa ira adicionar os arquivis

        for i in range(1, 100):
            carregar = ExemploModel(objeto1=f"informacao111{i}", objeto2=f'dados111 {i}')
            carregar.save()
        return render(request, "carregar2.html")

    def post(self, request): # na requisição post a função ira carregar o csv
        form = ContatoForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            #============================
            '''Seu Código'''
            # ============================
            for i in range(1,100):
                carregar = ExemploModel(objeto1=f"informacao222{i}", objeto2=f'dados222{i}')
                carregar.save()



            return redirect('index')

        return render(request, "carregar2.html", {'form': form})
```

htmls

exemplo 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

exemplo 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controlando as duas requisições e ambas podem inserir dados

Comment: Ainda não está indo para o banco de dados. :/

Comment: atualizei a resposta, dê uma conferida.

Comment: Reproduzi o código só adaptando para os nomes do projeto e tive um erro: ValueError: The view emissao_certificado.views.presenca didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. 

Substitui novamente deixando como estava anteriormente e esse erro permaneceu. :/

Comment: Em vez da view generic base, tenta só com a função carrega, dentro dela faça uma query pesquisando o dados se não tiver a query adicionar, aqui testei com django 3.0

Comment: Oi, Jeferson. Tenho atualizações sobre o projeto. Ele mostra o seguinte erro:

```Exception Value: 
expected string or bytes-like object```. Este erro está acontecendo no seguinte trecho de código da minha `views`:

`cria_certificado = ParticipanteCertificado.objects.get_or_create(participante=participante, data=formulario.data)`


Eu fiz o teste utilizando um pandas dataframe e consegui ler. Após algumas análises, corrigi um problema no `forms` que faltava pedir **todos** os campos do model `Evento` e, então, consegui progredir. Infelizmente, estou presa neste erro agora.

Comment: , pela mensagem o esperado é um literal ou bit.

Comment: Esse data=formulario.data que está com esse impasse. Só que não entendi o q ele refere ao que exatamente.